# Opening Camera in React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am developing using react native expo mobile app. I want to open camera. Also I don't want to use hooks.

I don't want to maintain state therefore I don't want to use hooks.
I have written code below. But its not working:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

export default function TakePic() {

    const __startCamera = async () => {
        const {status} = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()
        if(status === 'granted'){
        // do something
        
        return (<Camera
                style={{flex: 1,width:"100%"}}
                    ref={(r) => {
                    camera = r
                }}
            ></Camera>);

        }else{
            Alert.alert("Access denied")
        }i


        }
        __startCamera();

}
```

In other file I call `TakePic` from a button :

```
<Button title="Open Camera" onPress={TakePic} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my react-native app, i need to pick a image for profile from camera or gallery. I used the following code, maybe can help you. I used **react-native-image-crop-picker** and **@react-native-community/cameraroll**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Proptype from 'prop-types';
import CameraRoll from '@react-native-community/cameraroll';

import {
  Container,
  OptionSmall,
  ButtonContainer,
  Texto,
  OptionTextSmall,
  Thumbnail,
} from './styles';
import { VMHSize } from '../../lib/DynamicSizes';
import RunToast from '../../lib/RunToast';

const PhotoHandler = ({ setImage }) => {
  const theme = useSelector((state) => state.auth.theme);
  const myLanguage = useSelector((state) => state.auth.myLanguage);
  const [imagem, setImagem] = useState('');

  const launchCamera = () => {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
    })
      .then((image) => {
        setImagem(image.path);
        setImage(image.path);

        CameraRoll.save(image.path, 'photo')
          .then(() => {
            if (myLanguage === 'pt_PT' || myLanguage === 'pt_BR')
              RunToast(
                'success',
                'Imagem guardada',
                'A imagem foi guardada na sua galeria.'
              );
            else
              RunToast(
                'success',
                'Image saved',
                'The image has been saved to your gallery.'
              );
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            if (myLanguage === 'pt_PT' || myLanguage === 'pt_BR')
              RunToast('error', 'Ocorreu um erro', err);
            else RunToast('error', 'An error has occurred', err);
          });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        if (myLanguage === 'pt_PT' || myLanguage === 'pt_BR')
          RunToast('error', 'Imagem não seleccionada');
        else RunToast('error', 'Image not selected');
      });
  };

  const launchGallery = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      cropping: true,
    })
      .then((image) => {
        setImagem(image.path);
        setImage(image.path);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        if (myLanguage === 'pt_PT' || myLanguage === 'pt_BR')
          RunToast('error', 'Imagem não seleccionada');
        else RunToast('error', 'Image not selected');
      });
  };

  const ChoiceImage = () => {
    return (
      <ButtonContainer>
        <Texto theme={theme} maxFontSizeMultiplier={1.2}>
          {myLanguage === 'pt_PT' || myLanguage === 'pt_BR'
            ? 'Inserir imagem de:'
            : 'Insert image from:'}
        </Texto>
        <OptionSmall onPress={launchGallery} theme={theme}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="image-album"
            size={VMHSize(811, 15)}
            color={theme.mainColor}
          />
          <OptionTextSmall theme={theme} maxFontSizeMultiplier={1.6}>
            {myLanguage === 'pt_PT' || myLanguage === 'pt_BR'
              ? 'Galeria'
              : 'Gallery'}
          </OptionTextSmall>
        </OptionSmall>
        <OptionSmall onPress={launchCamera} theme={theme}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="camera"
            size={VMHSize(811, 15)}
            color={theme.mainColor}
          />
          <OptionTextSmall theme={theme} maxFontSizeMultiplier={1.6}>
            {myLanguage === 'pt_PT' || myLanguage === 'pt_BR'
              ? 'Tirar Foto'
              : 'Take photo'}
          </OptionTextSmall>
        </OptionSmall>
      </ButtonContainer>
    );
  };

  const ImageChosen = () => {
    return (
      <ButtonContainer>
        <Thumbnail source={{ uri: imagem }} />
        <Texto theme={theme} maxFontSizeMultiplier={1.6}>
          {myLanguage === 'pt_PT' || myLanguage === 'pt_BR'
            ? 'Imagem seleccionada'
            : 'Selected image'}
        </Texto>
        <OptionSmall
          onPress={() => {
            setImagem('');
            setImage('');
          }}
          theme={theme}
        >
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="cancel"
            size={VMHSize(811, 15)}
            color={theme.mainColor}
          />
          <OptionTextSmall theme={theme} maxFontSizeMultiplier={1.4}>
            {myLanguage === 'pt_PT' || myLanguage === 'pt_BR'
              ? 'Retirar imagem'
              : 'Remove image'}
          </OptionTextSmall>
        </OptionSmall>
      </ButtonContainer>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Container theme={theme}>
      {imagem === '' ? <ChoiceImage /> : <ImageChosen />}
    </Container>
  );
};

PhotoHandler.propTypes = {
  setImage: Proptype.func.isRequired,
};

export default PhotoHandler;
```

Comment: wheres the style bit?